# Update OpenDNS IP from Android tablet/phone

Tags: tasker, dns, busybox

I want to use my Android tablet or phone to update my OpenDNS IP since there is no official OpenDNS client for Android. Is it possible?

As a bonus, I'd like to do this automatically whenever I connect to WiFi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUCCESS!!

I went through a free web service called dnsomatic (run by the folks at opendns)

It's as simple as signing up for an account and adding opendns to your services. No configuration beyond that.

For Android users busybox versions of wget are way behind and don't have options to use user names and passwords, so we will have to install and use cURL

The guide to install curl can be found here

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2362386

Once you have curl you can simply do things like updating your opendns ip

```
curl -u opendnsusername:password http://updates.dnsomatic.com/nic/update?hostname=opendnshostname
```

Next you need to setup tasker to run this command when your device connects to WiFi.

Make a net profile that runs a task when connected to your WiFi ip or Mac address.

Press the "+" button in tasker to add a new task and select "scripts" and then "run shell"

Add the line of code above

```
curl -u opendnsusername:password http://updates.dnsomatic.com/nic/update?hostname=opendnshostname
```

This will make tasker execute the command when you connect to WiFi

Answer (score 2):

OK, I know I'm *way* late, but here's an alternative I'd like to share that may be of help.

Just open your browser at
https://email:password@updates.opendns.com/nic/update?hostname=your_opendns_network_label to update your IP -- and that's it. On the email part, use "%40" as an @ and "%2E" as a dot, ie, write "someone%40somewhere%2Ecom" instead of "someone@somewhere.com".

Credits to "rotblitz" at https://support.opendns.com/entries/23217700-Is-there-an-IP-Updater-for-OpenDNS-using-android for this nice tip.

As doing it automatically, sorry, no ideas but the aforementioned Tasker... hey, maybe IFTTT for Android?